# Given a string containing numbers, What is the best way to extract these?

Tags: list, haskell, types

I have a list of strings as follows;

["75","95 64","17 47 82"]

How can I convert this to a list of Ints;

```
[75,95,64,17,47,82]
```

My instinct is to use map and an anonymous function?

Comment: What does your current conversion code look like already?

Comment: Do you also want to add three to the last element or is it a typo?

Answer (score 4):

Haskell has a few useful functions

```
read :: String -> Int -- Restricted for clarity
map  :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
words :: String -> [String]
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So you give `map` a function and a list and it will apply your function to each element of the list. Now knowing this, you should be able to solve it yourself.

As Gabriel pointed out you'll also need `concatMap` and `words` to make sure that your string only has 1 number in it. `words` will split the string into a string of words and `concatMap` will run it over each element and smash the result back together.

Do know that read will blow up in your face if you're not careful since if the string is malformed it will call `error` which will terminate your program. If this is a concern, a similar process can be followed with

```
 mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
 readMaybe  :: String -> Maybe Int -- Restricted for clarity
```

from `Data.Maybe` and `Text.Read` respectively.

Comment: Don't forget the `words` function.  He will need that, too, since some of his strings contain multiple numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
func theList = (map read . concat . map words) theList
```

you will need to specify the type when you use this unless it can be inferred

```
(func ["75","95 64","17 47 82"])::[Int]
```