# Read strings as ints haskell

Tags: haskell

is there anyway I could read a string as an integer?

For example reading

```
triangle = ["1"
           ,"2 3"
           ,"4 5 6"]
```

as `[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]`

```
convertToInt :: [String] -> [[Int]]
convertToInt [] = []
convertToInt (x:xs) = **(somehow convert x to list of ints)** : convertToInt xs
```

Not sure how to procede, are there any inbuilt functions for this?

**edit: thanks! This is the solution**

```
convertToInt :: [String] -> [[Int]]
convertToInt [] = []
convertToInt (x:xs) = (map read (words x)) : convertToInt xs
```

Comment: Very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384384/given-a-string-containing-numbers-what-is-the-best-way-to-extract-these

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started

```
>> let str = "1 2 3"
>> words str
["1","2","3"]
>> map read (words str) :: [Int]
[1,2,3]
```

**Edit**

Since you've now figured what you need to do, I wanted to show you another solution, that might get you thinking a bit more about Haskell

```
convertToInt :: [String] -> [[Int]]
convertToInt = map (map read . words)
```

Try and figure out how it works - your understanding of Haskell will improve dramatically.